# How does the Seduction mechanism work? Why does AI never targets player for seduction?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I started playing as a female character with attractive trait. Nobody seduced me even though all my neighbors had the seduction focus. Then I tried starting again, with Ironman mode on, and then seduction events started occurring. It has happened every time. I think you don't receive seduction events from AI if you're playing non-iron man mode. But that can't be right.

After reading the decisions file, I couldn't find anything that would affect how many people would want to seduce one target.

Can someone explain how does seduction mechanic work? How does the AI select their target?

Comment: You are most likely not important enough.

Comment: @Nix I've started as Countess of Dax who holds 3 out of 4 counties in Duchy of Gascone. Later I userped duchy of Gascone too. In another test I started as countess of blois and received duchy of blois from Charlemagne. Then I was also granted title of designated regent. I think That makes me important.

Comment: Hmm, alright. It seems you've already made some research. Perhaps enough that you can make an answer yourself? Answering your own question is encouraged here on Stack Exchange, it might benefit others ... and welcome to the site, by the way. :)

Comment: By doing that research I have found nothing to cause that issue. I even introduced two custom traits in my game like Buxom and Callipygous which increase sexual attraction of my character. While they help securing aid in my plots it doesn't attract any murderers or seducers to my character. All I can say then it is probably a dev bug. So I don't think I am qualified to answer that @Nix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like it was a bug in previous versions of CK2. With the new DLC the Horselords out there, it appears to have been fixed. Now I am annoyed because no matter how chaste a wife i choose, someone always manages to seduce her. If I am playing as female, there will be some action targeted at me as well. I can gladly announce that I have been assassinated several times as well.

Comment: Last sentence is the reason I read through all CK2 questions I stumble upon :-)

Comment: NPCs using seduction too much is a common critique of the way of life DLC. There are several mods availabel on Steam workshop which tune it down.